# PHP searchTerms() function - Looping though array to find words beginning with a "

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to write a function that takes a search string as a parameter and returns an array of all search terms in the string. Every value in the string is considered a search term, except for the ones wrapped in double quotation marks: these phrases should be treated as a single search term. I'm assuming that all values in the string are separated by exactly one space and that no search string has an odd number of double quotation marks, that is, all beginning quotation marks have a matching set of ending quotation marks.

Here is my code so far:

```
function searchTerms($words)
{
    $split = explode(" ", $words);
    foreach ($split[0] == """) {
            return $values;
        }
    }
    return $split;
}
```

It's not working. It gives me a "Notice: Array to string conversion" when I try to run it. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks - all help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The synatx highlighting makes an error obvious

Comment: I know, I'm just not sure what I need to do to fix it -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to:

Use single quotes (eg `$split[0] == '"'`)

or

Escape the double quote (eg `$split[0] == "\""`)

Also, it looks like you are missing code. Where does `$values` come from and why is there an extra `}`?

Why are you doing a foreach with a boolean condition?

`foreach ($split[0] == """)`

This is not how [foreach's](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) work.

You might consider changing it to:

```
$words = "Hello World";
$split = explode(" ", $words);
foreach ($split as $word) {
    echo $word;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The above would output to the page:

```
Hello
World
```